# Redis: How do I expire items from a sorted set after 24 hours?

Tags: redis, nestjs

I was using Redis in my NestJs app and was pushing certain values using zadd.

I wanted to know how can I set an expiration time for each item pushed into the set and expire them after 24 hours.I tried the below code but it seems to be deleting all the items in the sorted set.

// Push item into sorted set

```
redis.zadd(`Notifications`, Date.now(), JSON.stringify(data));
```

// Delete expired items from sorted set

```
redis.zremrangebyscore(`Notifications(${key})`, '-inf', Date.now());
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this issue by doing the following

// Push item into sorted set

```
redis.zadd(`Notifications`, moment().add(86400, 'seconds').unix(), JSON.stringify(data));
```

// Delete expired items from sorted set

```
redis.zremrangebyscore(`Notifications(${key})`, '-inf', moment().unix());
```